# Opera 15+ extension - inline installation from addons.opera.com

Tags: opera, opera-extension

I have extension published in addons.opera.com catalog. Is there a possibility in addons.opera.com "inline" installation from my site, as it done in the ChromeWebStore https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/
When extension hosted in the ChromeWebStore and User can initiate installations "inline" from my site (click button), but user no longer have to leave my site to install his.

Comment: AFAIK no. There's no `chrome.webstore` object in Opera.

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported. See the documentation here: https://dev.opera.com/extensions/inline-installation/

Comment: Opera have recently removed inline install functionality, (that page now returns a "not found" error)

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported yet, but we're looking into it.

Comment: Has Opera now removed the inline install functionality in line with chrome also removing it? as the inline install functionality of my Opera browser extension no longer seems to work

Answer (score 0):

It seems Opera did have an Inline Install functionality for a while, but have now apparently removed it, due to the functionality being removed from the Blink browser engine that Opera is based on.